# How to use React hooks to determine if sidebar should show?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have read some introductions on React Hooks and want to make a simple app with a button in the header component, which determines if the main app should show the sidebar. The button sets the variable `showSidebar` in the header, and I want to read it again within my main component. The code for actually showing the sidebar is stripped out for brevity.

This is `index.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from "./header";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h1>Sidebar toggler</h1>

      <p>
        Should I show sidebar? <b>{showSidebar.toString()}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And this is the `header.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function Header() {
  const [showSideBar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);
  const toggleSidebar = () => setShowSidebar(!showSideBar);

  return (
    <header>
      Button in header toggles sidebar:
      <button onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>
        Toggle sidebar (state: {showSideBar.toString()})
      </button>
    </header>
  );
}
```

I am new to React, but do not understand why the state does not update in index.js? I also made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/toggle-sidebar-using-react-hooks-6kyn0) with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` is stores *local* state, for comparison you can think of it similar to `setState` in a class component (although in reality they aren't [*exactly* equivalent](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)). Therefore, setting `setShowSidebar` in `App` won't reflect the same value as that set in `Header` and vice versa.

It doesn't look like `Header` needs any form of local state if it's simply changing state of the outer component, you can pass in an event handler and any relevant state `Header` needs as props instead

**index.js**

```
function App() {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);
  const toggleSidebar = useCallback(() => setShowSidebar(value => !value));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header onClick={toggleSidebar} showSideBar={showSidebar} />
      <h1>Sidebar toggler</h1>
      <p>
        Should I show sidebar? <b>{showSidebar.toString()}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**header.js**

```
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      Button in header toggles sidebar:
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>
        Toggle sidebar (state: {props.showSideBar.toString()})
      </button>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is declaring a separate state in Header which you shouldn't do, because it has nothing to do with parent's state. Pass the parent state and a callback to update the parent state as a props to the header. Pass `showSidebar` as props to the Header component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from "./header";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
     // Pass prop here
      <Header 
        showSidebar={showSidebar} 
        toggleSidebar={()=>{setShowSidebar(!showSidebar)}}
         />
      <h1>Sidebar toggler</h1>

      <p>
        Should I show sidebar? <b>{showSidebar.toString()}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

// and then in your Header,
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      Button in header toggles sidebar:
      <button onClick={props.toggleSideBar}>
        Toggle sidebar (state: {props.showSideBar.toString()})
      </button>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep state `showSidebar` in the parent component (where you need to read it) and pass the functionality to change it to the header component (where you need to change `showSidebar`)

To do move `toggleSidebar` to `index.js`

```
const toggleSidebar = () => setShowSidebar(!showSideBar);
```

and pass the function to the Header component like this

```
<Header toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
```

now invoke it on clickEvent in Header component like this

```
<button onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>
```

remember to include the prop in your Header component

```
export default function Header({toggleSidebar}) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your `toggleSidebar` function in `App.js` itself, and pass `toggleSidebar` function and `showSidebar` state in `Header` component as props.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true)
  const toggleSidebar = () => setShowSidebar(!showSidebar)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header showSideBar={showSidebar} onClick={toggleSidebar} />
      <h1>Sidebar toggler</h1>

      <p>
        Should I show sidebar? <b>{showSidebar.toString()}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      Button in header toggles sidebar:
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>
        Toggle sidebar (state: {props.showSideBar.toString()})
      </button>
    </header>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-giuz6?fontsize=14)